# Single random post in homepage

Tags: get-posts, homepage

I want to display single random post in it's entirety in the homepage.I've tried many methods, but the main issue was that it won't display the content, only heading, or display content, but only an excerpt.

Now I have this code:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

One problem is that it doesn't display full post, only excerpt.Another problem is that it displays only heading and content and I want all the things I get in single.php.The biggest problem is that my custom code:

```
<?php

if(in_category('afghanistan')) {
$recent = new WP_Query("pagename=asia/afganistanas"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile;
}
else {
echo "Klaida!";
}
?>
```

which displays a page inside of post depending on the category of post doesn't word in index, but does work in single.php

**Is there any method to use a copy of single.php in index and give it a random post to load every time the page is refreshed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to show the full post: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#More_about_.24more

> I want all the things I get in single.php

possibly copy **all** the code from **within** the loop of single.php into the loop of your random post.

> my custom code ... doesn't work in index

the `in_category()` code might only work within the loop or needs refining - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Comment: Michael Thanks a lot.It worked except my custom code which requires to reset the loop, and if that's done it shows all the posts, but I guess it's another topic